# Google Analytics is installed, but no session data is showing

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-analytics

We have Google Analytics installed in a site. The analytics snippet is a direct copy/paste from the GA Admin site.

The GA Property shows hundreds of hits per day & thousands per month.  Those are expected numbers.  However, the audience overview shows all zeros: 0 Sessions, 0 Users, 0 Pageviews, etc.

Here's a screen shot of the installed GA snippet, taken from production.
[image: GA snippet]

Looking in the console, Google Analytics returns a 200 on the script request & on page view requests.  Page view requests are being sent to `https://www.google-analytics.com/collect?[analytics-data]`.

Using the Chrome extension, Google Analytics Debugger (found [enter link description here](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/google-analytics-debugger/jnkmfdileelhofjcijamephohjechhna/related?hl=en)), it appears the website is working as expected.

Lastly, there are no errors or warning in the console.  This is not a new property.  The UA code was generated years ago & was used, with displayed data, until recent.  The theme was replaced & we believe the analytics stopped reporting at this point.

Appreciate any & all direction.

Answer (score 0):

First, check on your live site with the new theme if the GA code is working.
Secondly, Check GA to see if there are any filters that are causing data to disappear.

Hope this helps,

Cheers Analytics ML.

Comment: Thx Analytics MI.  I confirmed the GA is working via the developer console.  I sent a test `ga( 'send', 'pageview' );`, which appears to respond well, showing an HTTP 200 response on the Network Pane.  Please do let me know if there's a better way to evaluate.  As for the filters, this is an area I'm not familiar with.  I will investigate.

Comment: It looks like this is a filter issue
Go to google analytics admin
view > filters and check if there is any filter that is causing the error